# Are there any tools to convert XML/XSLT or HTML/CSS to Graphics?

Tags: c#, graphics, printdocument

I am wondering, is there maybe a tool that can convert simple HTML/CSS (or just HTML) or XML/XSLT to a Graphics object?

I need to put some data on a PrintDocument and using the Graphics object is just *so* tedious. So are there any tools that can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I hear that a browser is a nice tool for rendering HTML/CSS.

Comment: Obviously you should re-read the question... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out...maybe it helps:
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/